# Errors list<String> is not a subtype of type <String>

Tags: firebase, flutter, flutter-android

// I am trying this code and it is not adding to the firebase

```
void checkItemInCart(String shortInfoAsId, BuildContext context) {
  EcommerceApp.sharedPreferences
          .getString(EcommerceApp.userCartList)
          .contains(shortInfoAsId)
      ? Fluttertoast.showToast(msg: "Item already in Cart.")
      : addItemToCart(shortInfoAsId, context);
}

addItemToCart(String shortInfoAsId, BuildContext context) {
  List tempCartList =
      EcommerceApp.sharedPreferences.getStringList(EcommerceApp.userCartList);
  tempCartList.add(shortInfoAsId);

  EcommerceApp.firestore.collection(EcommerceApp.collectionUser)
      .document(EcommerceApp.sharedPreferences.getString(EcommerceApp.userUID))
      .updateData({
    EcommerceApp.userCartList: tempCartList,
  }).then((v){
    Fluttertoast.showToast(msg: "Item Added to Cart Successfully");

    EcommerceApp.sharedPreferences.setStringList(EcommerceApp.userCartList, 
tempCartList);

    Provider.of<CartItemCounter>(context, listen: false).displayResult();
  });
}
```

// it is giving these errors

The following _TypeError was thrown while handling a gesture:
type 'List' is not a subtype of type 'String'

When the exception was thrown, this was the stack:
#0      SharedPreferences.getString (package:shared_preferences/shared_preferences.dart:98:35)
#1      checkItemInCart (package:e_shop/Store/storehome.dart:331:12)
#2      sourceInfo. (package:e_shop/Store/storehome.dart:301:31)
#3      _InkResponseState._handleTap (package:flutter/src/material/ink_well.dart:993:19)
#4      _InkResponseState.build. (package:flutter/src/material/ink_well.dart:1111:38)
...
Handler: "onTap"
Recognizer: TapGestureRecognizer#47ccb
debugOwner: GestureDetector
state: ready
won arena
finalPosition: Offset(380.3, 334.6)
finalLocalPosition: Offset(22.8, 31.6)
button: 1
sent tap down

Comment: could you tell me where this error shows up? in which line?

Comment: that is the whole error it is not telling me at which line.

Comment: It's saying that error in 98th line

Answer (score 1):

the problem is in .getString(EcommerceApp.userCartList) you have to set an index to it because EcommerceApp.userCartList returns a list use it something like this

```
.getString(EcommerceApp.userCartList[0])
```

Comment: I tried it and it is giving me this error:

Comment: The method 'contains' was called on null.
Receiver: null
Tried calling: contains("Phone : Samsung Galaxy note 10 12GB RAM 128GB")

Comment: it is because EcommerceApp.userCartList[0] returns "Phone : Samsung Galaxy note 10 12GB RAM 128GB" this value and there is no value in the EcommerceApp.sharedpreferences with that name  so check if the name that you stored and trying to get is the same.

Answer (score 0):

thanks all for helping.
all I needed to do is change the getString to getStringList

an now it is working.